# Encrypt in java and Decrypt in IOS For AES 128 bit

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, encryption

I have to Encrypt in java and Decrypt in IOS Objective-C using AES 128 bit

I have this Java program

```
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

public class EncryptionDecryptionAES {
    static Cipher cipher;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String plainText = "AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption";
            String Enc       = Encrypt(plainText,"testkey");
            System.out.println("Enc :" + Enc+":");
    }

    public static String Decrypt(String text, String key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
        byte[] b = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int len = b.length;
        if (len > keyBytes.length)
            len = keyBytes.length;
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
        byte[] results = new byte[text.length()];
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        try {
            results = cipher.doFinal(decoder.decodeBuffer(text));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Erron in Decryption");
        }
        return new String(results, "UTF-8");
    }

    public static String Encrypt(String text, String key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
        byte[] b = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int len = b.length;
        if (len > keyBytes.length)
            len = keyBytes.length;
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        System.out.println(keyBytes);
        System.out.println(keySpec);
        System.out.println(ivSpec);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

        byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        return encoder.encode(results);
    }
}
```

I have Objective-C code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    NSString* str = @"wLmnAsH0wEUlk/mYEBPUSQr0pMsRIFw5kgsAMr7UpuwjJo7MoxoqyBvZmPWM5DrS";
    NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",[data description]);
    NSString* theData = [self Decrypt: data  WithKey:@"testkey"];


    NSLog(@"%@", theData);
}


- (NSData *)Encrypt:(NSString *)data WithKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [self AESOperation:kCCEncrypt OnData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] key:key];
}


- (NSString *)Decrypt:(NSData *)data WithKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[self AESOperation:kCCDecrypt OnData:data key:key] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (NSData *)AESOperation:(CCOperation)operation OnData:(NSData *)data key:(NSString *)key {
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          [data bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

When I am running the code in iOS

```
 
2016-09-25 22:03:21.346 Test[15603:1297217] Hello
2016-09-25 22:03:21.346 Test[15603:1297217] 
2016-09-25 22:03:21.346 Test[15603:1297217] Success
2016-09-25 22:03:21.347 Test[15603:1297217] (null)
```

I am excepting here the output for as "AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption" but getting null.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Java snippet is using `PKCS5Padding` and iOS `PKCS7Padding`

Comment: @Brandon Essentially PKCS#5 padding is PKCS#7 padding in practice are interchangable. The only real difference the PKCS#5 padding is specified for a 8-byte block size and PKCS#7 padding is specified for up to 255 bytes block sizes. See [PKCS padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

Comment: Notes: 1. Don't use the key as the IV, it should be a random bytes, generally prefixed to the encrypted data, it is also an invalid length. 2. Insure the key is the exact size, 128, 192 or 256 bits, "testkey" is an invalid key length. 3. Sice you are getting a null result there is a parameter error, incorrect buffer size or most probably incorrect key size. 4. examine the `cryptStatus` and add that to the question as well, error values are there it help. 5, you are passing `kCCBlockSizeAES128` for the key size, this is incorrect, use kCCKeySizeAES128, kCCKeySizeAES192 or kCCKeySizeAES256.

Comment: @zaph plainText  is  "AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption" , key is "testkey" and encrypted data is "wLmnAsH0wEUlk/mYEBPUSQr0pMsRIFw5kgsAMr7UpuwjJo7MoxoqyBvZmPWM5DrS"

Comment: The input data to `CCCrypt` must be in binary, "wLmnAsH0wEUlk/mYEBPUSQr0pMsRIFw5kgsAMr7UpuwjJo7MoxoqyBvZmPW‌​M5DrS" is not binary, it looks like Base64 encoded 88 bytes.  Correct the key, key length, iv and iv length. Supply the values in hex just prior to and immediately after the call to `CCCrypt. If you expect the encryption methods to fix-up improper parameters interoperability probably will not work.

Comment: @zaph Changed my Key to "3d090e3f7a72d51a" and iv to "207ecf137586424952b8cfc3e7fd8ce9bd839a916c07b9d5f34d250315d91aa9"    String iv = "207ecf137586424952b8cfc3e7fd8ce9bd839a916c07b9d5f34d250315d91aa9";
    byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
    byte[] ivb = iv.getBytes("UTF-8");
    int ivlen = ivb.length;
    if (ivlen > ivBytes.length)
        ivlen = ivBytes.length;
    System.arraycopy(ivb, 0, ivBytes, 0, ivlen);    The generated output is "JMK+Jgtaj0DBm2bSuLlamKHCdEm3MKYHaX6AhUIagpjcDhfGK9Z/11pvvgPueLmJ" which doesn't look binary to me

Comment: Add additional information, especially code to the question where everyione will see it and it can be formatted. The first step is to fully understand binary, character encoding and Base64 encoding.

Comment: @zaph My knowledge in java is limited  and I thought following code is doing encoding

   byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    return encoder.encode(results);


I tried another code using Oracle PL/SQL DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt , which returns me '24C2BE260B5A8F40C19B66D2B8B95A98A1C27449B730A607697E8085421A8298DC0E17C62BD67FD75A6FBE03EE78B989' but Still I get same error

Comment: @ShibiNs : Note that Android code is using UTF-8 string encoding and iOS is using NSUnicodeStringEncoding. Make sure that both are in same encoding format.

Comment: did yo find any help ?